# Terminate a client connection when a reverse proxied websocket server crashes

Tags: nginx, websocket, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get nginx to close its connection to a client when a connection to a reverse proxied websocket server is lost.

Previously, I had a [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) client connecting directly to a [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) process. For each connection, websockify forks a child process to handle it. If that child process crashed (such as by being killed), noVNC would detect the lost connection allowing it to be handled in an appropriate manner.  Such as displaying an error message and a reconnect button.

If I change this setup to use nginx as a reverse proxy, the noVNC client is unable to determine that the connection from nginx to websockify has been terminated. The result of this is that the noVNC client is frozen.

How do I get nginx to detect that websockify has been terminated and close the connection it has to noVNC?

In case it has any bearing, the previous method used an unencrypted connection between noVNC and websockify. With nginx there is an encrypted connection between noVNC and nginx and an unencrypted connection between nginx and websockify.